# Im using v-model for an input and name for the other. Im trying to understand the different ways to access their data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form with some inputs, im submitting the form and displaying the data in a modal. It works but im not sure im doing it the right way and the code looks messy.

**This is how the HTML looks** (without the modal for the sake of simplicity):

```
<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="getValues">
    <label>Last Name: </label><input type="text" name="lastName">
    <br>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**This is the Vue instance and getValues function**:

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        lastName: ''
    },
    methods:{
        getValues(submitEvent){
            this.lastName = submitEvent.target.elements.lastName.value
        }
    }
})
```

In order to shorten the code a bit, i implemented v-model:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="getValues">
    <label>First Name: </label><input type="text" v-model="firstName">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Vue**:

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        firstName: ''
    },
    methods:{
        getValues(submitEvent){
            firstName = this.firstName
        }
    }
})
```

It works too but `firstName = this.firstName` is confusing to me. I tried changing the names to understand the references but it wont work. Is the variable firstName inside getValues being used at all or is the value being rendered due to v-modal two way binding (and i cant tell because the modal isnt rendered until the form is submitted)?

[Heres a JSFiddle including both approaches.](https://jsfiddle.net/edhbpj86/4/)

Which one is correct? Are they interchangeable? Whats the difference between them?

Comment: `v-model="firstName"` automatically binds the input to the `data` value you have (`this.firstName`). Your `firstName = this.firstName` is just creating a new global variable with that name _(global because there is no `var` or `const` or `let` in front of it)_. Right now, it's useless. But if you want to send it somewhere else, why not

Comment: @blex Thanks for the reply. So, in short, that function is useless if all i want to do is print the data in a modal?

Comment: Exactly. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/gp2xb3qh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is using events, the other is using 2-way binding.

When you submit the form, the associated event fires a method (`@submit.prevent="getValues"`). Inside this method you read the value of `name` and set the `lastName` property to equal it.

When you do `v-model="firstName"` Vue sets up 2-way binding between the input field value and the `firstName` property.

You see the difference in that when you type into the input box, it immediately updates the property. Behind the scenes Vue is handling the change event, and updating the property. Equally, if you modified the data property some other way, the value in the input box would also update.

There's also a 3rd option of 'simple' binding. This is achieved by using the `v-bind` tag. This will do the updating of the data property in the same way, but won't modify the input box value 'in reverse' if changed elsewhere.